# C# GDI How to draw text to fit in rectangle?

Tags: c#, gdi, drawtext

We can draw a text inside a rectangle easily.

[image]

Currently I would like to draw a text inside and FIT a rectangle.

[image]

Please help.

Comment: what exactly does fit mean? you want the text having the same hight and the same width as the rectangle?

Comment: Yes you got it. The text string may be stretched according to the height and width of that rectangle.

Comment: Please post the code you're using for the first version, so that people can show you how to adapt it to the second version.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think the easiest way is to scale the graphics output to the destination rectangle:

```
public static class GraphicsExtensions
{
    public static void DrawStringInside(this Graphics graphics, Rectangle rect, Font font, Brush brush, string text)
    {
        var textSize = graphics.MeasureString(text, font);
        var state = graphics.Save();
        graphics.TranslateTransform(rect.Left, rect.Top);
        graphics.ScaleTransform(rect.Width / textSize.Width, rect.Height / textSize.Height);
        graphics.DrawString(text, font, brush, PointF.Empty);
        graphics.Restore(state);
    }
}
```

Comment: Any more perks in your GraphicsExtensions you can share?

Comment: @Nissim I'm afraid I wrote the class just to answer this question with valid code.